# NameError in User#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model named User and am referencing it in the form. The form is as follows:

```
<%= form_with(model: user, local: true) do |f| %>
<p>Who is the participant?</p>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :person %>
<%= f.text_field :input %>
</div>
<p>What gifts would they like?</p>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :gifts %>
<%= f.text_field :gifttext %>
 </div>
 <p>Who, if anyone, is their spouse? If they don't have one you can leave 
 this field blank</p>
 <div class="field">
 <%= f.label :person %>
<%= f.text_field :input %>
</div>
<p>What gifts would they like? If there is no spouse then you can leave this 
field blank.</p>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :gifts %>
<%= f.text_field :gifttext %>
 </div>
<div class="actions">
 <%= f.submit %>
 </div>
 <%= link_to 'Done', user_results_path(@user) %>
 <% end %>
```

Then I get this error:

```
NameError in User#new Showing C:/Sites/sstwo/app/views/user/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined local variable or method `user' for
#<#<Class:0x5590668>:0x41b5ff0> Did you mean?  @user Extracted source (around line #1): 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

I'm sure it's a quick fix so I'm willing to learn. If any more details are needed please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first line, you're using `user`, should be `@user`

```
form_with(model: @user, local: true)
```

Source: https://m.patrikonrails.com/rails-5-1s-form-with-vs-old-form-helpers-3a5f72a8c78a

Comment: I now get this error.

NoMethodError in User#new
Showing C:/Sites/sstwo/app/views/user/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `users_path' for #<#<Class:0x5590668>:0x4d1a620>
Did you mean?  user_results_path

Comment: In the tutorial I linked in form_with, when you use a model rails "When you set the model argument then scope and url are automatically derived from it. This behaviour is similar to form_for." When you set @user rails thinks that you have something like `resources :users` on your routes, so it can use the generated helper on the form. It looks like you don't, so the expected `users_path` method doesn't exist and it throws an error. This is mostly a guess, please confirm the information by looking at your routes file or by using `rake routes`

Comment: Here is my routes page:

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'user#new'
  get 'user/results'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end

Comment: In [this section](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#generating-paths-and-urls-from-code) of the guide you linked, it is saying that you need to add something like `, as: 'user'` to generate the helper `users_path` for the url. Although I strongly recommend that you use resourceful routes instead of non-resourceful.